# Regex - how to check while typing (even if the text is not complete)

Tags: java, regex

I want to set a regex to email address in a way that it will check while I am typing (using JFXML):

```java
String reg = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
System.out.println( pattern.matcher("eshaka@horm").matches());
```

this is a code I used, but this can only detect if the current text is a valid email or not.

1. Not only detect when I have typed a valid address.
2. I want to detect if what I have typed so far in within the scope of an email address and not me from typing an illegal character.

Example:

```
emails is some_one@somemail.com
```

`some_o` is in the scope of an email. but not a full email. so should let me keep typing but should not accept it as an email.

`some_one@some@ma` this one contains two `@s` which is illegal. I want the text field to stop the user from entering that `@`.

Comment: you want a textformatter (which uses the regex) on the textfield

Comment: @kleopatra can you please show me a code sample how i can do this. i know how to set a formatter. but making the textformatter is a little confusing

Comment: and how to make a regex check if the text is not invalid yet

Comment: do some research - there are enough answered questions with examples on SO :)

Comment: that's 2 separate problems, solve them one after the other

Comment: well.. i already know how to set the regex to the text area. what i need to figure out is that.. and most of the question body is also about that

Comment: What you would ideally do is convert the regex to a finite state automaton. As long as whatever input you do have makes successful state transitions through the automaton, then you have a legal prefix of a valid email address (assuming you started with the correct regex). If you are in a final state *and* there is no more input, then the input is a valid email address. But I don't think you will have any success using the Java regex engine and the unaltered regex you started with.

Comment: But let's say for the sake of argument that a valid email address was `^\w+@\w+\.\w{3}$`. You could test against: `^(\w*|\w+@?|\w+@\w+\.?|\w+@\w+\.\w{1,2}|(\w+@\w+\.\w{3}))$`. On a valid email group 2 will be present. Your actual regex is more complicated, but you get the idea.

Comment: [See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o89CDR/1/)

Comment: @Booboo that’s actually very easy with Java’s regex engine

Comment: @Holger I certainly missed that! It seems I am a veritable fount of misinformation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Matcher.hitEnd()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd--). This method is precisely for determining whether more input could change the result. So if the pattern does not match and the end has not been hit, appending more characters at the end would not fix the problem. This doesn’t preclude that inserting at a different position could solve it:

```
static final Pattern VALID_MAIL = Pattern.compile(…);// insert actual pattern here

enum Status { VALID, INVALID, INCOMPLETE }

static Status check(CharSequence cs, boolean complete) {
  Matcher matcher = VALID_MAIL.matcher(cs);
  if(matcher.matches()) return Status.VALID;
  return complete || !matcher.hitEnd() ? Status.INVALID : Status.INCOMPLETE;
}
```

To simulate typing:

```
String[] samples = { "eshaka@horm", "some_one@some@ma",
                     "some_one@somemail.com", "@domain.name" };

for(String input: samples) {
  StringBuilder typing = new StringBuilder();
  input.codePoints().forEach(cp -> {
    System.out.println(typing.appendCodePoint(cp) + ": "
        + check(typing, typing.length()==input.length()));
  });
  System.out.println();
}
```

With the pattern used in your question, it results in:

```
e: INCOMPLETE
es: INCOMPLETE
esh: INCOMPLETE
esha: INCOMPLETE
eshak: INCOMPLETE
eshaka: INCOMPLETE
eshaka@: INCOMPLETE
eshaka@h: INCOMPLETE
eshaka@ho: INCOMPLETE
eshaka@hor: INCOMPLETE
eshaka@horm: INVALID

s: INCOMPLETE
so: INCOMPLETE
som: INCOMPLETE
some: INCOMPLETE
some_: INCOMPLETE
some_o: INCOMPLETE
some_on: INCOMPLETE
some_one: INCOMPLETE
some_one@: INCOMPLETE
some_one@s: INCOMPLETE
some_one@so: INCOMPLETE
some_one@som: INCOMPLETE
some_one@some: INCOMPLETE
some_one@some@: INVALID
some_one@some@m: INVALID
some_one@some@ma: INVALID

s: INCOMPLETE
so: INCOMPLETE
som: INCOMPLETE
some: INCOMPLETE
some_: INCOMPLETE
some_o: INCOMPLETE
some_on: INCOMPLETE
some_one: INCOMPLETE
some_one@: INCOMPLETE
some_one@s: INCOMPLETE
some_one@so: INCOMPLETE
some_one@som: INCOMPLETE
some_one@some: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somem: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somema: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somemai: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somemail: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somemail.: INCOMPLETE
some_one@somemail.c: VALID
some_one@somemail.co: VALID
some_one@somemail.com: VALID

@: INVALID
@d: INVALID
@do: INVALID
@dom: INVALID
@doma: INVALID
@domai: INVALID
@domain: INVALID
@domain.: INVALID
@domain.n: INVALID
@domain.na: INVALID
@domain.nam: INVALID
@domain.name: INVALID
```

So for certain inputs, we can determine early that the input will stay invalid when only typing ahead, while others, like `eshaka@horm` can only considered invalid when we say that it is supposed to be complete.

You can also use this feature to locate the problem:

```
static void feedback(CharSequence input) {
  System.out.append(input).append(": ");
  Matcher matcher = VALID_MAIL.matcher(input);
  if(matcher.matches()) System.out.println("Ok");
  else if(matcher.hitEnd()) System.out.println("Type ahead");
  else {
    for(int p = 0; p < input.length(); p++)
      if(!matcher.region(0, p).matches() && !matcher.hitEnd()) {
        System.out.println("(First) problem at position "+p);
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

```
for(String input: samples) feedback(input);
```

```
eshaka@horm: Type ahead
some_one@some@ma: (First) problem at position 14
some_one@somemail.com: Ok
@domain.name: (First) problem at position 1
```

Comment: the part with `region` and `hitEnd` is superbe!